# Why do I get a syntax error and unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' error in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax, echo

```
case in $angreifenQ
    j) enemieHealth=$(( $enemieHealth - $weaponDamage ));;
    n) echo "Du bist ein Franzose"
       echo "Warum spielst du eigentlich das Spiel?";; 
esac

if $(( $enemieHealth <= 0 )); then
        echo "Der Gegner ist gestorben!"
elif $(( $enemieHealth > 0 )); then
        echo "Der Gegner hat noch ${enemieHealth} Leben!"
fi
```

Why do I get those errors?

```
./anfang.sh: line 125: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./anfang.sh: line 127: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) is often more helpful than bash when it comes to tracking down missing quotes or keywords.

Comment: Downvote: The code you posted does not exhibit the problem you describe.  It has other problems, which are readily identified by http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also check the spelling of "enemy".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which line your error message refers to, but as far as we can see there is no missing `"`. What you can try first is to correct above errors.

First, the right syntax for `case` should be:

```
case $angreifenQ in
```

not:

```
case in $angreifenQ
```

And to compare numbers, remove leading the `$`:

```
if (( $enemieHealth <= 0 ))
...
elif (( $enemieHealth > 0 ))
```

As suggested in comment, you should consider using [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to report obvious errors in your script as missing opening or closing `"`.

Comment: Yes, but that does not explain the error reported.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited but nothing in the given code can explain the error message. Using spellcheck.net should be a good start.

Comment: Indeed, nothing in the code presented explains the errors reported, but those are themselves pretty self-explanatory.  They even explain why the shell *doesn't* complain to the OP about the error you've spotted.

Comment: You're right and I upvoted your answer. A short answer could be "check first that all `"` are used in pairs". But seeing such obvious errors in the script IMHO the best advice is to check the script globally.

Comment: The link should be to http://shellcheck.net/ ("shell check"), not http://spellcheck.net/ ("spell check"). See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck -- where the source code to this tool lives -- making its canonical name and URL very clear.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy English is not my native language and it may occur that I mix up some words. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

The code you presented has several problems, starting with the misplacement of the `in` keyword first mentioned by @SLePort.  That `bash` is not reporting those to you is not explained by the code you presented, nor are the error messages you report actually seeing.

On the other hand, that you receive the error messages you report instead of ones I would expect from your code is consistent with there being an unmatched `"` character somewhere preceding what you presented, just as the first of your messages describes.  Indeed, I can obtain your messages by prefixing the code you present with a `"`.

More likely than a stray `"` by itself, however, is a quoted string from which you omitted the trailing `"`.  Look backward from the code you've presented to find such a thing.  If you've a text editor with syntax coloring for shell script then that might help speed your search.